# Vector of Vectors to 2D Repa Array

Tags: haskell, repa

What is the cleanest way to turn a [Vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.0/docs/Data-Vector.html) of vectors of unboxed doubles into a [repa](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.2/docs/Data-Array-Repa.html) `Array U DIM2 Double`?

The most obvious way is to concatenate all the unboxed vectors into one and pass it to [fromUnboxed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.2/docs/Data-Array-Repa-Repr-Unboxed.html#v:fromUnboxed), but that feels a bit clumsy.  Is there a better alternative?

Comment: The thing is, repa `Array U` is basically just a newtype wrapper around an `UV.Vector` anyway, so I don't reckon there's much of a better solution.

Comment: Ah right, thanks @leftaroundabout.  Add an answer if you like so I can accept it